# unable to compile x86 .s file

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, terminal, x86, x86-64

I tried compiling my asm .s file in the terminal of VSC and it didn't work although it worked just yesterday :(

The code:

```
.global main

main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp

end:
    movq $0, %rdi
    call exit
```

What I entered in terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\runan\Desktop\x86> gcc -no-pie -o power power.s
```

The error message I got:

```
gcc : The term 'gcc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ gcc -no-pie -o power power.s
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gcc:String) [], Comman 
   dNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I checked and the file is in the folder. I tried set Path= ... command and then gcc -v but it didn't work either.

Comment: You need to run this command from the WSL shell, not the Powershell.